# Usage of Hibernate OGM with cloud MongoDB Atlas M0 (Free Tier)

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-ogm, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to use MongoDB Atlas M0 (Free Tier) for my JAVA EE application, now I am using:

- Local MongoDB database (v4.0.4)
- Hibernate Core "hibernate-core 5.3.6.Final"
- Hibernate OGM "hibernate-ogm-mongodb 5.3.1.Final"
- Java application server WildFly 15.0.0.Final.

With a local database a pair MongoDB and Hibernate OGM works like a charm, but when I tried to connect Hibernate with Mongo Atlas on free tier to test cloud database, I am was not able to have a working connection, because mongodb driver throws an exception *com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream*

I will provide two versions of my persistence.xml, first is working fine with localhost and second is what I used to connect to cloud.

**working localhost version:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">

    <!--   @@@   MongoDB   HIBERNATE   OGM   PERSISTENCE   UNIT   @@@   -->
    <persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnitNoSQL" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>

        <class>org.companyname.model.UserEntity</class>
        <class>org.companyname.model.ItemEntity</class>

        <properties>

            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="localhost:27017"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="databasename"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database" value="true"/>

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**not working atlas cloud version:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">

    <!--   @@@   MongoDB   HIBERNATE   OGM   PERSISTENCE   UNIT   @@@   -->
    <persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnitNoSQL" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>

        <class>org.companyname.model.UserEntity</class>
        <class>org.companyname.model.ItemEntity</class>

        <properties>

            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="cluster0-clustername-shard-00-00-raa4n.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-clustername-shard-00-01-raa4n.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-clustername-shard-00-02-raa4n.mongodb.net:27017"/>

            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="databasename"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database" value="true"/>

        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.username" value="atlas-user-name"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.password" value="atlas-user-password"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.authentication_mechanism" value="SCRAM_SHA_1"/>

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Like a host I used replica sets URIs from "standard connection string" from helping window in the Atlas account, because with "short SRV connection string" Hibernate throws *org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: OGM000072: Unable to configure datastore provider*, so I think there is no support of  this type of connection yet.

So with this last persistence.xml configuration I had following error:

```
20:02:01,094 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
20:02:01,175 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] (cluster-ClusterId{value='5c5497a97aea6111622c7540', description='null'}-cluster0-clustername-shard-00-02-raa4n.mongodb.net:27017)
Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-clustername-shard-00-02-raa4n.mongodb.net:27017: com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:570)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:441)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:295)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:106)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Hibernate tries to connect to each shard (00-00, 00-01, 00-02), but with all throws this exception.

What I tried to do to fix the problem:

- using mongo-java-driver version 3.9.1 instead of Hibernate 3.6.3 built-in, but both drivers work with the same problem
- my IP is added (my app is deployed from my laptop) to my atlas account IP Whitelist
- I am able to connect fine to cluster from Mongo Shell and MongoDB Compass
- I had a doubts about "hibernate.ogm.mongodb.authentication_mechanism", but "SCRAM_SHA_1" and "BEST" didn't worked for me
- and finally I tried to make a connection to the cluster from Java directly (without Hibernate)

with

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb+srv://atlas-user-name:atlas-user-password@cluster0-clustername-raa4n.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");
```

or

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://atlas-user-name:atlas-user-password@cluster0-clustername-shard-00-00-raa4n.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-clustername-shard-00-01-raa4n.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-clustername-shard-00-02-raa4n.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-clustername-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true");
```

and both cases worked fine, I was able to make a connection and to use the database without problems.

So my problem is why Hibernate throws this kind of exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that something is not right in the way Hibernate OGM creates the client.

I think the easier way to check this now for you is to override the `MongoDBDatastoreProvider` and provide an initialized MongoClient.

You can do this by extending MongoDBDatastoreProvider and overriding the method createMongoClient. Something like:

```
package org.myprojects;

import org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider;

public class MYCustomMongoDBDatastoreProvider extends MongoDBDatastoreProvider {

    @Override
    protected MongoClient createMongoClient(MongoDBConfiguration config) {    
       return MongoClients.create(...);
    }

}
```

then use the property `OgmProperties.DATASTORE_PROVIDER` to use your datastore provider:

```
hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider = org.myprojects.MYCustomMongoDBDatastoreProvider
```

In this example I'm setting it in the hibernate.properties file but you can set it where it makes more sense for your project.

**EDIT**: Additional explanations about the error.

[I think the problems is that we are not using the factory to create the mongo client](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-ogm/blob/master/mongodb/src/main/java/org/hibernate/ogm/datastore/mongodb/impl/MongoDBDatastoreProvider.java#L155).

**EDIT 2**: The problem might be caused by a lack of support for SSL.
[An issue has been created](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-1555) and contains more information

Comment: Could you also create an issue for this, please? Here's the link to the JIRA: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/OGM/issues/OGM-1509?filter=allopenissues

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that the link I use in the previous comment is wrong. This is the right one: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-1555

Comment: Could check my answer as answered, please?

Comment: Oh sure, thank you for giving me a hint where to look for the problem I had on connection

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem. I, additionally, enabled SSL and the connection was success:

`<property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.driver.sslEnabled" value="true"/>`

Comment: It's a great solution, will check it, thx @MaximSharai